# How to add cross-reference for a numbered item inside a drawing box?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, cross-reference

I am preparing a document with word 2010. I used a lot of cross references. But for some reasons I had to insert some numbered items into a drawing box. Now, when I'm trying to add cross-references for this item word cannot find it. Is there any process of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a textbox, use a floating table (ie a table but change it's Properties for Text Wrapping to Around, instead of None).  You can position it on page like a textbox, and cross-references to styles contained in the table will appear in your cross-reference dialog box.